# How do I override the bootstrap navbar css in rails 4 using scss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I can override other elements like `body` and `jumbotron` but any changes I make to the navbar don't do anything.

I've made sure there are no precompiled assets in /public.

My application.css.scss file is this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

// ensure the body isn't overlaped by the fixed header since we're using that
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

// this does nothing!
.navbar-default {
  .navbar-text {
    color: red; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm feeling very stupid now, but I'm compelled to admit my mistake just in case anyone else makes the same one and can learn from mine.

I wasn't using the navbar-default class, I was using navbar-inverse... that's why the overrides didn't work!

Doh!  Thank for the answers anyway.  They helped me work it out at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Use `!important` in the style

and give the styles for `particular class` for `navbar`

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {

    color: red !important; 

}
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/m50i6HDnhu)

Answer (score 0):

Use the @bootstrap-variables to customize your navbar, for example:

_variables.scss:

```
$navbar-height:                    50px !default;
$navbar-margin-bottom:             $line-height-computed !default;
$navbar-border-radius:             $border-radius-base !default;
$navbar-padding-horizontal:        floor(($grid-gutter-width / 2)) !default;

$navbar-collapse-max-height:       340px !default;

$navbar-default-color:             #777 !default;
$navbar-default-bg:                #f8f8f8 !default;
$navbar-default-border:            darken($navbar-default-bg, 6.5%) !default;
```

More info http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables